# How do I change the "design" of a <div>?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the design of a div (color, width, text margin etc). How can I do so? I prefer not using the `<style type="text/css">`

Comment: If you don't want to use CSS you can try magic.

Comment: @Nadav by doing this you're going against all the standards that have been designed over the years and will make it incredibly hard for you later down the line when you want to make changes.

Comment: You should read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS to understand why you should use CSS.

Comment: Can you give one good reason for not using CSS style?

Comment: I just didn't want <style></style> but Aradmey answered my question. I don't understand why so many negative votes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.

```
<div style="background-color:YOUR_COLOR; width:YOUR_WIDTH; margin:MARGIN;">TEXT</div>
```

Uses:

- `background-color` is your background-color. You can also use `color` for text color. Refer to colors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp).
- `width` is your chosen width for the div. You can also use px at the end of the number to define pixels length. Refer to a tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp)
- `margin` is defining the margin from all directions (top, bottom, left and right). You can also define specific margins for every direction by using `margin-left` `margin-right` `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`. Refer to a tutorial about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp).